# Python - any property file or data format that is mostly free-form?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm about to roll my own property file parser. I've got a somewhat odd requirement where I need to be able to store metadata in an existing field of a GUI. The data needs to be easily parse-able and human readable, preferably with some flexibility in defining the data (no yaml for example).

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
this is random text that is truly a description

.metadata.
owner.first: rick
owner.second: bob
property: blue
pets.mammals.dog: rufus
pets.mammals.cat: ludmilla
```

I was thinking I could use something like '.metadata.' to denote that anything below that line is metadata to be parsed. Then, I would treat the properties almost like java properties where I would read each line in and build a map (or object) to hold the metadata, which would then be outputted and searchable via a simple web app.

My real question before I roll this on my own, is can anyone suggest a better method for solving this problem? A specific data format or library that would fit this use case? I would normally use something like yaml or the like, but there's no good way for me to validate that the data is indeed in yaml format when it is saved.

Comment: You have the same issue if the input format is yaml or your own homebrew format. What will you do if someone leaves out a crucial '.' or ':' character?

Comment: When the focus is in that area of the GUI open another small window. At critical points of entry, as the user types, check syntax and report exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 problems:

1. How to fit two different things into one box.

   If you are mixing free form text and something that is more tightly defined, you are always going to end up with stuff that you can't parse. Then you will have a never ending battle of trying to deal with the rubbish that gets put in. Is there really no other way?
2. How to define a simple format for metadata that is robust enough for simple use.

   This is a hard problem - all attempts to do so seem to expand until they become quite complicated (e.g. YAML). You will probably have custom requirements for your domain, so what you've proposed may be best.
3. How to parse that format.

   For this I would recommend [parsy](https://github.com/python-parsy/parsy).

   It would be quite simple to split the text on `.metadata.` and then parse what remains.

Here is an example using parsy:

```
from parsy import *
attribute = letter.at_least(1).concat()
name = attribute.sep_by(string("."))
value = regex(r"[^\n]+")
definition = seq(name << string(":") << string(" ").many(), value)
metadata = definition.sep_by(string("\n"))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> metadata.parse_partial("""owner.first: rick
owner.second: bob
property: blue
pets.mammals.dog: rufus
pets.mammals.cat: ludmilla""")

([[['owner', 'first'], 'rick'],
  [['owner', 'second'], 'bob'],
  [['property'], 'blue'],
  [['pets', 'mammals', 'dog'], 'rufus'],
  [['pets', 'mammals', 'cat'], 'ludmilla']],
 '')
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a simple and nice solution. There is a [YAML library](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) in Python:

```
import yaml

output = {'a':1,'b':{'c':output = {'a':1,'b':{'c':[2,3,4]}}}}
print yaml.dump(output,default_flow_style=False)
```

Giving as a result:

```
a: 1
b:
  c:
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
```

You can also parse from string and so. Just explore it and check if it fits your requeriments.

Good luck!

Comment: yaml is great, but i can't validate the format in the description field, so I need something a little more fre-form. The last thing I want is to have people entering invalid yaml format and I can't parse it.